# Selenium Thread.sleep showing error? How do I resolve the issue

Tags: java, selenium, thread-sleep

[image: The image]

I tried using wait function too that to showed error.

Comment: Hover over that line. You should see what the error actually is. Or try and compile it and see what the error is.

Comment: And please [do not post pictures of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Post text instead.

Comment: And finally read the documentation for the [`sleep` method.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long)). You'll notice it throws exceptions you're not handling.

Comment: Rather than sleeping you should have a look at https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Timeouts.html

Answer (score 0):

`Thread` is part of another library, not part of the Selenium plugin.

Add this line to your code and compile:

```
import java.lang.Thread;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an actual error. It's just an indication that you have to allow the [InterruptedException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/InterruptedException.html) to propagate up the call stack, as an example, by adding a *`throws`* clause to the method in turn and letting the caller determine how to handle the interrupt. This can involve our not catching the exception or catching and rethrowing it.

There are some methods in Java that throws [InterruptedException](https://www.baeldung.com/java-interrupted-exception#what-is-an-interruptedexception). Some examples are:

- Object class:

  - *`Thread.sleep()`*
  - *`Thread.join()`*
  - *`wait()`*
- BlockingQueue:

  - *`put()`*
  - *`take()`*

---

### Solution

To add the `throws` clause you need to modify the code block as follows:

```
public static void main() throws InterruptedException {
    // some lines
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    // remaining lines
}
```